# Divi Sidebar Works OK Homepage Problem on Blog

Tags: wordpress, module, blogs, sidebar, divi

first post here.

This is a weird one. I have installed a Sidebar module in Divi which works perfect on the homepage here: https://addictionhelp.agency/

But the Aweber sign up form seems to jump/skip/stagger and the author photo and bio are jumped immediately to the 'most recent posts' on the BLOG page here:  https://addictionhelp.agency/blog

I have been in touch with Divi support for four hours this morning and they said delete the et-pb cache file, I think it was, but that made no difference.

I suggested it might be a bug with the blog module (???) as this didn't happen on the homepage but they said they didn't know and would escalate it.

I have removed W3 Cache and done a hard refresh and reboot and everything I can think of so  I am totally stumped.

Any advice would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0):

The blog page has the sidebar set as sticky. Try to find the Sidebar module that you added and remove the scroll effects under the modules "Advanced" tab. Should fix your problem.